# Cosets/ Cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ and $H=\langle a^2\rangle$. Find all the right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Additional info: I understand that a right coset of $H$ in $G$ is of the form $Ha=\{ha:h \in H\}$. But I am not sure if the cyclic groups are finite or infinite, and I don't understand how to find right cosets. Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you name any coset at all? Can you then find an element of $G$ not in that coset?

Comment: I am sorry, but is $gp(a)$ a notation for cyclic group generated by $a$?

Comment: I think the identity e is a right coset, since e is in G and since H is a subgroup e should be in H. Therefore e is a right coset. @Alex B.

Comment: Yes it is the notation for a cyclic group generated by a.@ SwapnilTri

Comment: You yourself said, in the question, that cosets are of the form $Ha$. Then how come $e$ is a coset?

Comment: Because e is G and e is in H. Therefore e*e=e is a right coset of the form ha where h is in H and a is in G. This is what I gather.I'm not sure how to find right cosets, this is why I asked the question.

Comment: $e*e=e$ is an element, not a coset. Look at this. If H={$a,b,c,d,e$}, the a right coset is $Hg$={$ag,bg,cg,dg,eg$}. Please, note that H is a set, and so is Hg. I don't know how to put in the braces.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to recall that the cosets of a group partition it.

Since $H:= \{ a^{2k} \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$ contains the group identity element, we see $Ha = \{a^{2k + 1} \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$.  But then $H \cup Ha = \{ a^k \mid k \in \mathbb Z \} = G$, so $H$ and $Ha$ are the only possible cosets.

Comment: What if $|G|=3$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $\sigma\colon G\to G$ defined by $\sigma(x)=x^2$. This is a homomorphism, because $G$ is abelian, being cyclic. The kernel of $\sigma$ is
$$
\ker\sigma=\{x\in G:x^2=1\}
$$
while its image is $H$.

If the order of $G$ is odd, no element $x\ne1$ can have the property that $x^2=1$, so $\sigma$ is injective, hence surjective. So, in this case, $H=G$ and, of course, there's only one coset.

If the order $n$ of $G$ is even, there is *exactly* one element $x\in G$ such that $x^2=1$ and $x\ne 1$, precisely $a^{n/2}$. (Why?) So the kernel of $\sigma$ has two elements and $|H|=|G|/|\ker\sigma|=n/2$. Therefore $|G|/|H|=2$ and so there are exactly two cosets; since $a\notin H$ (why?), the cosets are
$$
H\quad\text{and}\quad Ha.
$$

If $G$ is infinite, then $G\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and the image of $H$ under this homomorphism is $2\mathbb{Z}$. Again the cosets are
$$
H\quad\text{and}\quad Ha.
$$

Answer (score 1):

since the index of $H$ in $G$ is $2$, it has two distinct right cosets, namely $H$ and $H_a$ 
$\{a^2,a^4,a^6,a^8,a^{10}\}$
and $\{a,a^3, a^5, a^7, a^9\}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

As written in the question, cosets are of the form $Ha$ where $a\in G$. Clearly, $He=H$ is a coset of H in G.

Now use the fact that $aH=bH$ iff $ab^{-1} \in H$.

**Note :** i don't know if this is the correct way to say it, but in $G/H$, elements of $H$ are considered as identity elements.